# python/java script: how to use sub protocol on a python server?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, raspberry-pi

in websocket i found out that to connect to a rasberry pi with port fowarding it's complexe, when the client tries to connect the serveur sees it but not
the client only see that he had been accept after he put's this error

```
start serveur
start 5677
connect
Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 674, in transfer_data
    message = yield from self.read_message()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 742, in read_message
    frame = yield from self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 815, in read_data_frame
    frame = yield from self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 884, in read_frame
    extensions=self.extensions,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/framing.py", line 99, in read
    data = yield from reader(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/streams.py", line 668, in readexactly
    yield from self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/streams.py", line 458, in _wait_for_data
    yield from self._waiter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 380, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 304, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 285, in result
    raise CancelledError
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/server.py", line 169, in handler
    yield from self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "webserveur.py", line 6, in Time
    a=await websocket.recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 434, in recv
    yield from self.ensure_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 658, in ensure_open
    ) from self.transfer_data_exc
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "webserveur.py", line 19, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1388, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 445, in select
    fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and this what appens on the client side:
[image: client piscture]
so to help i thought about using sub protocols but i found no code on google or stack overflow so i ask the question `how can i use sub protocols with a python server`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello server</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <script>
        alert("started");

        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://public ip/", "chat-1.0");//chat-1.0 is only to show that i want to use this sub protocol and it hasn't been here for the test with the error below
        ws.onopen = function (event) {
        alert("connect");
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

the serveur

```
print("start serveur")
import asyncio
import websockets
async def Time(websocket, path):
   print("connect") 
   a=await websocket.recv()
   print(a)
    
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()  
print("start 5677") 
start_server = websockets.serve(Time, "0.0.0.0", 5678)


websocket2=loop.run_until_complete(start_server)


loop.run_forever()
```

`thanks for helping`